# Run command (or batch file) in every subfolder

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, recursion, subdirectory

I want to run a script (which I have in a `.bat` file already)

```
"c:\Flac\flac.exe" -8 *.wav --verify --delete-input-file --replay-gain
```

in all subfolders of a main folder.

If I take this `.bat` file and copy/paste it into any folder and run it, it works great and I get the expected results. However, if I have a main folder with 50 folders that I want to do this in, it takes forever to copy and paste that file 50 times.

Been trying to figure out the syntax for using (I assume) the command 
`FOR /R`
but can't seem to get it right.

For example let's say directory tree is this:

> ```
> c:\
>      FLAC
>           flac.exe
>           flac BATCH.bat
>      Music to be converted
>           1
>           2
>           3
> ```

I want to run the `C:\FLAC\flac BATCH.bat` in every subfolder of `C:\Music to be converted`

I've tried

```
FOR /R "C:\Music to be converted" %X IN (*.wav) DO "C:\FLAC\flac BATCH.bat" "%X"
```

but this doesn't work. I need the `FOR /R` command to go through the subfolders, don't I?

Comment: What happens if you run something like this from the command prompt, `For /D %A In ("Music to be converted\*") Do @(PushD "%~A" & "C:\Flac\flac.exe" -8 *.wav --verify --delete-input-file --replay-gain & PopD)`?

Comment: That did it thank you! Can I ask what PushD and PopD does?

Comment: Did you try the command help, `PushD /?` and `PopD /?`, the two basically step in and out of a directory. I've, put my response into an official answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment.

From the command line:

```bat
For /D %A In ("C:\Music to be converted\*") Do @(PushD "%~A" & "C:\Flac\flac.exe" -8 *.wav --verify --delete-input-file --replay-gain & PopD)
```

Or as a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /D %%A In ("C:\Music to be converted\*") Do (PushD "%%~A"
    "C:\Flac\flac.exe" -8 *.wav --verify --delete-input-file --replay-gain
    PopD)
```